# dynamically created labels are overridden

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i am working on one application in which i have added 5 labels dynamically in a function.when i recall the same function the labels are overridden on the previously created labels in spite of releasing the labels on each creation.

```
    for(int i = 1; i < [array count]; i++)
    {   
        CGRect lblframe = CGRectMake(count, ycord, width, height);
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:lblframe];
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17];
        label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(188/255.f) green:(149/255.f) blue:(88/255.f) alpha:1.0];;
        label.text = [arr objectAtIndex:i];

        count = count + xcord;
        [subcatScroll addSubview:label];           
        [label release];
   }
```

Comment: "when i recall the same function the labels are overridden on the previously created labels in spite of releasing the labels on each creation", can you explain more on your requirement?

Comment: I have some dynamically created labels in a scrollview. When I click on one value of labels lets say the first one in my horizontal scroll , another set of values appear in dynamically created labels just below the upper scrollview. Now When I click on second value of Main scrollview then the values on the lower scrollview are overwritten with the new values. I tried to release the previous labels but the issue was not solved.

Comment: Do you actually need to create new labels? can't you just replace the text of those already existing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write below code before for loop to get your requirement:

```
for (id object in [subcatScroll subviews]) {

    [object removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely follow, so correct me if I'm misunderstanding.
Every time you call this function, you are adding a number of new labels. So if you call this function the second time, assuming 'count', 'ycord', 'width', and 'height' correspond with the values that the first call had, you are obviously adding a second group of labels in the same place as the first ones which are now directly on top of one another. You are not "overriding" the old labels, you are placing a second group directly ontop of the old ones.

Calling "release" on each label, only means you are decreasing the retainCount by 1. This number is used for memory management only. This means if you now remove the labels from the view the memory is released.

```
CGRect lblframe = CGRectMake(10.0, ycord, 200.0, 20.0);
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:lblframe];
NSLog(@"retainCount of label: %d", [label reatinCount]); // will print "1" since you called alloc
[self.view addSubview:label];
NSLog(@"retainCount of label: %d", [label reatinCount]); // will print "2" since adding to subview increases retaincount by one
[label release];
NSLog(@"retainCount of label: %d", [label reatinCount]); // will print "1" since you released
[label removeFromSuperview]; // will decrease retainCount of label to "0" and therefore free the memory
```

so say you wanted to remove the previously created labels from the view, you would have to do so. Either keep a reference to each of them and call "removeFromSuperview" on each of them.

If the only thing in the view where you're adding the labels, you can also just remove every subview that was added to it like so:

```
// remove old labels
for (UILabel *aLabel in [self.view subviews]) [aLabel removeFromSuperview];

NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"I", @"II", @"III", @"IV", nil];
for (int i=0; i<[myArray count]; i++) {
    float ycord = i*40.0;
    CGRect lblframe = CGRectMake(10.0, ycord, 200.0, 20.0);
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:lblframe];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17];
    label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(188/255.f) green:(149/255.f) blue:(88/255.f) alpha:1.0];;
    label.text = [myArray objectAtIndex:i];

    [self.view addSubview:label];
    [label release];
}
```

I hope this helped, but providing further info on what you're trying to do may make it easier to help you.

Comment: for (UILabel *aLabel in [self.view subviews]) [aLabel removeFromSuperview];     yes it works thanks jan.