# iOS 5: Strange Behaviour of addSubview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, uiview, xcode4.3

I'm trying to create an activity indicator in my app. I'm using a storyboard and I have created a button which is pushing another view.

Here is how I open another view:

```
- (IBAction)openView {  
    NSLog(@"View is loading");
    @try {
        UINavigationController *nav = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewOpenSegue"];
        [nav setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
        [self presentModalViewController:nav animated:YES];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Error");
    }
    @finally {
        NSLog(@"View loaded");
    }
}
```

Everythings good so far. I got the log before view gets opened, and the 2nd log after it is fully loaded.

But when I want to use addSubview method, I am having a weird behavior.

```
NSArray *subviewArray2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"View" owner:self options:nil];
loadingView = [subviewArray2 objectAtIndex:0];
```

That's how I load my view. And I add/remove like this:

```
[self.view addSubview:loadingView];
//@try block
//@catch block
//@finally
{  
[loadingView removeFromSuperview];  
}
```

I expect the view appear and disappear on screen. But it appears for like 1 millisecond right before pushed view appears then disappear suddenly.

If I add this way under viewDidLoad, it appears.

I have seen similar questions but they didn't help me out. Anyone has a clue? Should I try something else?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm curious - why are you using @try/@catch blocks?

Comment: because I thought it's the best solution for detecting borders of activity. it shows loading (supposed to...) while trying, gives the error in case there's any then finally, remove loading panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because I wasn't using a `selector`. Please refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919879/uiactivityindicator-not-working-properly/2919983#comment13232027_2919983).

Here's the optimized code:

```
[self.view addSubview:loadingView];  
[self performSelector:@selector(openView) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this nib file View.xib have file owner?

Answer (score 0):

it happen because first viewdidload execute than viewdidapper method. viewdidappear load every time u push or pop the view so write your code in viewdidload if you want to execute it very first of your view load.

Comment: I don't want to load first time, I want to load after I click on a button. So I write the code under - (IBAction)openView function. It already loads first time if I use under viewDidLoad, it doesn't load if I try later.

Comment: what is  appears for like 1 millisecond right before pushed view appears then disappear suddenly?

Comment: it's not important. problem is that it doesn't appear while a new view is opening.