# When is a UIView refreshed? Is it possible to force mid-function refresh?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiview, refresh

I have one function in the app I am working which sometimes takes a comparatively long amount of time compared to other actions. I would like for an image to appear while the function is executing to show the user that the app is still working properly.

The way I though it could be done is:

```
_checkImpossibleImage.hidden = NO;
bool ratioIsPossible = [PaintGame isPossible:_paintChipRatio:_paintCanRatios];
_checkImpossibleImage.hidden = YES;
```

In essence, it would set the image to visible, execute the function, then set the image to invisible. However, the view does not seem to be updated until all the code in this section is executed. Here is the function overall:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0){
        // Do nothing (cancel option selected)
    } else {
        if (_buttonKey == @"New") {

            _checkImpossibleImage.hidden = NO;
            bool ratioIsPossible = [PaintGame isPossible:_paintChipRatio:_paintCanRatios];
            _checkImpossibleImage.hidden = YES;

            ...
        }
    ...
    }
}
```

Is there a way to force the current view to update or is there a better way to create a 'loading' popup while a function executes?

Comment: You might want to look into the [UIView documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/setNeedsDisplay), specifically `needsDisplay` which will force a redraw. However, I am not aware of a redraw that happens mid-function.

Comment: Basically the same problem: [UIActivityIndicator not working properly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919879/uiactivityindicator-not-working-properly)

Comment: This solution worked! Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't block the UI when doing this, I think it will be better if u just call the method that takes long amount of time in a separate thread.

Comment: I do not think it would work to call the function in a different thread because it is crucial for the following app behavior. It does not take a significantly long amount of time to complete, maybe 10 seconds, but I think it would be beneficial to notify the user that this event is taking place.

Comment: If the app can't continue until this method is completed you can show the user some "loading..." view before u call the method.

Comment: In fact 10s is too long to block the UI. You should process in the background, then send a notification (or similar) to have your app continue to the next step.

Comment: I am aware that it is a fairly long time, but I cannot really do anything to change that due to the nature of the problem and unfortunately there are no other actions that the user  would want or need to take until this is completed. However, what would I need to do to cause the function to run in the background and then send a notification?

Answer (score 0):

Drawing doesn't happen until the end of the run loop; there's no way to make it happen in the middle of your code. You can delay the call to `isPossible::` (which is a poor method name, by the way) until the next go-around of the loop by putting it on the main dispatch queue:

```
_checkImpossibleImage.hidden = NO;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        bool ratioIsPossible = [PaintGame isPossible:_paintChipRatio:_paintCanRatios];
        _checkImpossibleImage.hidden = YES;
        // More code to deal with the value of ratioIsPossible
});
```

Comment: I am not sure this would be an appropriate response since it occurs as a response to an alert view button press so presumably this function would not be run again until the next time the button is pressed. However, can you give me some advice on better naming conventions?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Why does the method need to be run again?

Comment: Well maybe I just do not really understand the solution that you suggested. When you say the next go-around of the loop what exactly do you mean? I am fairly new to using Objective-C and Xcode so I am not particularly familiar with the overall process and behavior.

Comment: I'm talking about the [run loop](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/MainEventLoop.html); it processes input, drains the top-level autorelease pool, and flushes drawn buffers to the screen. You have to let it loop to see any drawing results. Putting your `PaintGame` method on a queue lets the run loop go around once, so you see the results of previous drawing.

Comment: Okay, I understand that better now. The result you suggested here still does not seem to be having the desired effect but I will look into the comment you left on my original post as well. Thank you for your help.