# UIActivityIndicatorView doesn't always animate in "LaunchScreen.xib" while loading application

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

I just noticed that `UIActivityIndicatorView` doesn't always animate in "LaunchScreen.xib" while loading application.

Why? What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

The "Animating" option is enabled.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you calling web service after activity start animating?

Comment: @Rajpal Thakur What do you mean? I call dataTaskWithURL in viewDidLoad function

Comment: call dataTaskWithURL after delay a second..

Comment: @Rajpal Thakur Unfortunately, the same problem

Comment: i think you have connetted outlet also...

Comment: @Rajpal Thakur Which outlet? What do you mean? And why should it affect the activity indicator's animation?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919879/uiactivityindicator-not-working-properly

Comment: the problem is that he is doing it in LaunchScreen.xib so he cannot add Code to that xib file like any other file. unless they have changed that recently.

Comment: I tried the same thing yesterday: UIActivityIndicator in LaunchImage.xib. The same problem :-(